# transform mysql dataset into desire format (considering performance)

Tags: node.js

I have following timeseries data table,

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/HMRJMOlZ)**

| Id | Object_Id | Datetime | Sensor1 | Sensor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:01:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:02:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:03:00' | 5.5699381666667 | 81.342836833333 |
| 4 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:04:00' | 5.5668366666667 | 81.281143 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 48 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:48:00' | NULL | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

in above table, I have **sensor1**, **sensor2** upto **sensor1000** columns and each has millions of time series records.

I form a below query to fetch data,

```
 SELECT  datetime, sensor1, sensor2
 FROM     timeseries
 where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00'
```

Result

| datetime | sensor1 | sensor2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-24 22:01:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-24 22:02:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-24 22:03:00 | 5.56994 | 81.3428 |
| 2022-03-24 22:04:00 | 75.5668 | 81.2811 |

So far so good.

Now, I want to transform above dataset into array as shown below,

for sensor1,

```
{"timeseriesData": [[2022-03-24 22:01:00, 0], [2022-03-24 22:02:00, 0], [2022-03-24 22:03:00,  5.56994 ], [2022-03-24 22:04:00, 75.5668], [...], [...] ] }
```

for sensor2,

```
{"timeseriesData": [[2022-03-24 22:01:00, 0], [2022-03-24 22:02:00, 0], [2022-03-24 22:03:00,  81.3428 ], [2022-03-24 22:04:00, 81.2811], [...], [...] ] }
```

**Yes, I transform dataset in my backend code. Fyi, I use Node and I can transform result into desire format. The problem comes when I use many sensors eg sensor1, sensor2, ...., sensor40 and long range (starttime & endtime)** eg 6 months range then node throws,

> FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

In backend code, it has to go through each cell (sometime multiple times) and prepare the desire format using **LOOPs** and in such scenario it throws above **heap memory error**.

---

I tried transforming data using MySQL functions:  `json_arrayagg` & `json_object` with `union all` clause as shown below,

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM ( SELECT               
                            json_object(
                                          "timeseriesdata", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                                                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)*1000, 
                                                        sensor1
                                           ))                                   
                             ) AS obj
                        FROM 
                           timeseries 
                        where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00'
                         
  UNION ALL 
  
                         SELECT 
                            json_object(
                                          "timeseriesdata", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                                                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)*1000, 
                                                        sensor2
                                           ))                                   
                             ) AS obj
                        FROM 
                            timeseries
                        where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00'
                        ) x
```

**The problem** with this above query is, it is **SLOW** when you are querying **Medium** dataset (up to 3 months) and it **FAILS** when you are querying **Large** dataset  (eg 4 months or beyond) then it throws **json_arrayagg size error**.

FYI, To make it fast, I removed `union all` clause from above query and querying individual sensor data one after another which work bit faster. However, with large date range, it throws **json_arrayagg size error**.

I really have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: It looks like the only thing left is to split the datetime range into smaller chunks and process them sequentially.

Comment: You must not do this transformation in sql, it is not meant for this task. Either take @AntonIvanov 's advice about spliting your data up or use some kind of a data streaming solution like kafka to send the data downstream or use some other libraries that can manipulate big data fast.

Comment: As I mentioned, do not proceed in sql with this. It is difficult for me to understand the point of returning such a large resultset that causes memory problems. It is possible that your server's resources are too small, but more likely either your business requirements are not correct or you are using the wrong technologies to deal with your data. Can you please explain what you are trying to do with such a huge resultset that causes memory issues?

Comment: Basically, we want to prepare a csv data (selected time-range) for user to download.

Comment: The arrays in your question are in json format, not in a tabular format suitable for CSV. If you want to produce csv, then mysql can do that very quickly with select into outfile (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) statement without any transformations.

Comment: There is something called stream in mysql `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015279/how-to-use-node-mysql-without-loads-all-the-rows-into-the-memory` but I don't know how to use it. I tried by not working as expected.

Comment: @micronyks  Please seriously consider Shadow's Mar 22, 2024 at 12:25 comment and avoid ALL the aggravation of arrays (that run out of RAM) and any other solution.  MySQL to CSV is an optimum solution from what we are reading.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: create needed JSON value "by hands" using common string functions then save it to the file. This must be fast enough.

The file is local for MySQL server, the MySQL account must have FILE privilege.

Created file which contains needed JSON value than should be uploaded to the client (if there is no remote access to the MySQL server filesystem) and read into the program.

The query should look like (I have tested it on the provided dataset, and created JSON value is valid):

```
    SELECT '[{"timeseriesdata": [' AS value
UNION ALL
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('[', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)*1000, ',', COALESCE(sensor1, 0), ']' SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM timeseries
    WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '2021-01-20 22:01:00' AND '2024-01-20 00:17:00'
UNION ALL
        /* repeat for each separate sensor */
    SELECT ']},{"timeseriesdata": ['
UNION ALL
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('[', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)*1000, ',', COALESCE(sensor2, 0), ']' SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM timeseries
    WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '2021-01-20 22:01:00' AND '2024-01-20 00:17:00'
UNION ALL
        /* end of the block to be repeated */ 
    SELECT ']}]'
INTO OUTFILE ' {filename} '
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '';
```

Do not forget to adjust session `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` variables values.

You may need to add `` .. ORDER BY `datetime`.. `` into GROUP_CONCAT() parameters.. but I doubt it will be necessary.

I have added COALESCE() function which converts all NULL sensor values to zeros for to avoid the gaps in datetime. If you don't need in this and should skip these rows/datetimes then remove COALESCE() but add `.. AND sensorX IS NOT NULL ..` to WHERE clause.

Comment: This is absolutely horrendous and really should not be used. Your are basically trying to do a big text manipulatiin in sql, which is not what sql is meant to do. Let sql do its job: return tabular data and let something else do the transformation.

Comment: @Shadow I do not see the problem to return the value value created by this query immediately into the client, without file operations. It's enough to remove last 3 query rows and wrap it with `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SEPARATOR '')`. But OP tells that his dataset is too large and causes memory issue error on both server and client side depends on where he performs the operation. And I do not see how the chunks may help with this issue - anycase the client should process doubled data size while combining the data into single dataset.

Comment: I do see a huge problem whenever we try to force a relational database to return a non-relational (non-tabular) resultset, no matter whether it is through a file or through memory. If you need a different type of result, then either do the transformation downstream or do not use a relational database.

Comment: "anycase the client should process doubled data size while combining the data into single dataset" - this is where chunking could help.

Comment: Take the approach that JSON data storage will double your requirements for space, cpu, processing every day and DO NOT even TRY to use JSON for storage.  It will only make you regret taking this path as long as the application is used.  Performance will suffer, complexity makes it hard to find suitable (high value)  assistants when your business grows.